# Cumulative Stock Holding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a stock holding based on the below data.

[Input and Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLHnS.png)
I have tried using creating a transactions column (Starting  + UK Open POs - UK Sales).

Then used the below SQL code to create a stock holding.

```
Sum OVER (   TRANSACTIONS)
   [ <PARTITION BY No_ ]  
   [ <ORDER BY Date ]
```

But the problem is I don't want the stock holding to go into a negative. I want it to show 0, so when 960 units come in on 14/04/19 the stock holding is 921 units (960-39) instead of 116 units.

The column highlighted in yellow is my desired output. I need this over 5k SKUs (column no_)

Any help would be very appreciated.

```
    No_ Date    UK-Open PO  UK-Sales    Starting Stock  Trans.  Cumul Stock     Stock Level
111111  22/03/2019                47            100       53             53         53
111111  24/03/2019               330                     -330           -277        0
111111  31/03/2019               443                     -443           -720        0
111111  07/04/2019               85                      -85            -805        0
111111  14/04/2019  960          39                       921            116        921
111111  21/04/2019  960          112                      848            964        1769
111111  28/04/2019               100                     -100            864        1669
111111  05/05/2019               504                     -504            360        1165
111111  12/05/2019               606                     -606           -246        559
111111  19/05/2019               118                     -118           -364        441
111111  26/05/2019               400                     -400           -764        41
111111  02/06/2019               674                     -674          -1438        0
111111  09/06/2019               338                     -338          -1776        0
111111  16/06/2019               206                     -206          -1982        0
111111  23/06/2019               115                     -115          -2097        0
111111  30/06/2019  500          66                       434          -1663        434
111111  07/07/2019               33                       -33          -1696        401
```

Comment: Can you add sample data as text to the question (which we can use) as opposed to image(which we cannot use).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am new so apologies if this is an obvious question but how do you simply add a table of data? 'Paste as text' comes out in the wrong formatting.

Comment: If you are using ssms change the query to return results as text then copy and paste to the question using the edit button , highlight the pasted text and press ctrl/k (control k) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Hopefully this help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppressing the negative numbers as you are doing requires remembering what has happened on all previous rows.  Alas, this can't be done using window function.

The alternative is a recursive CTE:

```
with t as (
      select no_, date, starting_stock, trans,
             row_number() over (partition by no_ order by date) as seqnum
      from <table>
     ),
     cte as (
      select no_, date, trans, seqnum,
             starting_stock as stock_level
      from t
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select t.no_, t.date, t.trans, t.seqnum,
             (case when cte.starting_stock + t.trans < 0 then 0
                   else cte.starting_stock + t.trans
              end) as stock_level
      from cte join
           t
           on t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1 and
              t.no_ = cte.no_
     )
select *
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

You only need the `option` if the number of rows exceeds 100 from the recursion.

Comment: This works but i am getting "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion"
I have tried to add 'OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 ) at the end of the query but getting 'incorrect syntax near the keyword option.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. I will ideally I need 104 rows but i will limited to 100. When i add 'option (maxrecursion 0);' is tell me it is 'incorrect syntax'.....never mind.